# VB.Net DataSource for Control Generated at Run Time

Tags: vb.net, runtime, datasource

Can someone explain why specifying a DataSource for a ListBox (or other control) created at run time does not work?

This code:

```
Dim LB As New ListBox
Dim DT As New DataTable

DT.TableName = "Colors"
DT.Columns.Add("color")
DT.Rows.Add("red")
DT.Rows.Add("blue")
DT.Rows.Add("green")

LB.DataSource = DT

Debug.Print(CType(LB.DataSource, DataTable).TableName)
Debug.Print(DT.Rows.Count)
Debug.Print(LB.Items.Count)
```

Produces this output:

```
Colors
3
0
```

No error is generated, the name of the DataTable is picked up, but no rows are added to the ListBox as items!

Comment: Is this a winforms or webforms `ListBox`. In ASP.NET you need `DataBind()` after you've set the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ..

```
LB.DataSource = DT
LB.DisplayMember = "Color"
Me.Controls.Add(LB)
```

Comment: "Controls.Add" did the trick!  I was thinking that would add the listbox to my form, which I did not want, because I am using a ToolStripControlHost to pop up the listbox.

Comment: @oldvbguy .. you should vote this as the answer if this helped .. truly LB.DisplayMember that solved this out .. Controls.Add was just additional in my code .. :)

Comment: Good point about voting!  But, actually it was the Controls.Add, not setting DisplayMember that worked.  I left out DisplayMember from my sample just to keep it simple.  If you run my sample code and just add a DisplayMember you get the same result.  Controls.Add fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the datasource doesn't get read until there is something to display.  As soon as you add the control to the form that listbox has values from the datatable.  Mind you this is still probably not what you want, as the datatable doesn't appear to be compatible with the ListBox.  It returns Object to string data not the values.  A List(Of String) however is compatible and will do what you appear to want.

Answer (score 0):

The `Listbox` does except and display class objects especially ones that override the `ToString` function - this tells it what to display. And it can hold a `List(Of myClass)` as a datasource.

Example:

```
Public Class myClass
  Public Property owner As String
  Public Property title As String
  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return String.Format("{0} - {1}", Me.Owner, Me.title)
  End Function
End Class
```